# Referencing rowid in another field of an SQLite insert

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

```
CREATE TABLE data(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT NOT NULL);
```

I have a TEXT NOT NULL field "name", but on `INSERT`, the user might not give a name to put there. In this case, I would like to generate a name like `'data'+ROWID`. Can this (referencing the ROWID in another field, during INSERT) be done in SQLite?

pseudo code:

```
if( name == null )
    INSERT INTO data (name) VALUES ('data'+ROWID);
else
    INSERT INTO data (name) values ($name);
```

Answer (score 2):

In the definition of the table set the default value of `name` to an empty string:

```
CREATE TABLE data(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '');
```

Create an [`AFTER INSERT` trigger](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) that changes empty strings of `name` to your desired value:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_after_insert_data AFTER INSERT ON data
WHEN NEW.name = '' 
BEGIN
  UPDATE data 
  SET name = 'Data' || NEW.id
  WHERE id = NEW.id;
END;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/MM0OToD0).